# Rand method on array with use of range operator + array index

Tags: ruby, arrays, random

I have this little problem with this code: I want to pass parameter to this `random_select` method in form of array, and I want to have one random index returned. I know that It won't work due to the way that range operator works , for such purposes we have `sample` method. But can anyone explain me why is this code returning `nil` as one of its random value?

```
def random_select(array)
   array[rand(array[0]..array[4])]
end

p random_select([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your range is accessing to array values, not to array indexes:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array[0] #=> 1
array[4] #=> 5
array[0]..array[4] #=> 1..5
```

What you want is achievable in this way:

```
def random_select(array)
  indexes = 0...array.size #=> 0...5
  array[rand(indexes)]
end

array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Array.new(100) { random_select array }.uniq.sort == array #=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [`sample`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-sample)?

```
def random_select(array)
  array.sample
end
```

> Choose a random element or n random elements from the array.
>
> The elements are chosen by using random and unique indices into the
>   array in order to ensure that an element doesn’t repeat itself unless
>   the array already contained duplicate elements.
>
> If the array is empty the first form returns nil and the second form
>   returns an empty array.
>
> The optional rng argument will be used as the random number generator.